# write malloced memory between processes

Tags: c

Suppose I have started programs on one machine. Every program will first of all `malloc` a piece of memory. I am wondering how do I make one process's malloced address known to other processes so that they can use `mmap` to write other processes's that malloced piece of memory?

Comment: Which Operating System? Under Linux each process has its own address space so you cannot share pointers obtained via malloc() between different processes. I see the following options: (1) use shared memory with multiple processes or (2) use malloc() with multiple threads within the same process.

Comment: Windows is the same in this respect.

Comment: @mauro Thanks for your advice. That's just what I need. I think I will use `shmget` to do it.

Comment: Use posix instead of sysv (shmget).

Answer (score 0):

The comments suggest shared memory, which is appropriate for separate processes, but writing a multi-threaded program might be a better fit.  With `pthreads(7)` the `malloc`'ed memory can be directly accessed by each thread, and there's a rich set of concurrency control functions.